# GetShortPathNameW cannot find file specified

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get the short path name of a path that contains wide characters, here is the code I am using, it is always throwing an exception for file not found.  The file definitely exists, what am I doing wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace GetShortPathNameW_Test
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int GetShortPathNameW(String pathName, System.Text.StringBuilder shortName, int cbShortName);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Text.StringBuilder new_path = new System.Text.StringBuilder(1500);
            int n = GetShortPathNameW("\\\\?\\C:\\\\temp\\test1.txt", new_path, 1024);

            if (n == 0)
            {
                throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One rather major problem is that you throw an exception regardless of what `GetShortPathNameW` returns.

Comment: It's just the shortest possible code to show the problem.

Comment: That's just my point: it *doesn't* show the problem. If `GetShortPathNameW` worked the way you call it, you'd get some completely unrelated exception, which very well could be exactly what you're getting now. A simple `if (n == 0)` and noting that an exception gets thrown for you would address that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You explicitly call the Unicode version `GetShortPathNameW`, but do not specify the correct parameters for calling the Unicode version.

Firstly, rename the method to `GetShortPathName`. That is enough to get it to start working, without any other changes. Your parameters are still "ANSI" strings, but that's okay, since you're calling the "ANSI" implementation.

Secondly, you can add `CharSet = CharSet.Unicode` to your `DllImport` attribute to specify that you want the Unicode implementation. This also makes sure the strings get passed as Unicode strings. This will also make everything work as intended.

Nowadays, there should be no reason not to call the Unicode implementations of functions, but the default for `DllImport` cannot change without breaking backwards compatibility, so it needs to be specified for every function.

Comment: Thanks, that works.  Is the prepended "\\?\" necessary?  I was following the advice on the msdn page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa364989(v=vs.85).aspx when I added this.

Comment: @ScottLogan It's hard to tell. For the specific file name you're dealing with now, it should not be necessary. In general, for very long path names, it may be necessary. Unconditionally using it, however, may be undesirable, because `\\?\...` disables some things you may be used to, as documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In particular, it disables common uses of relative paths.